# VLOOKUP not displaying correct data

Tags: excel, vlookup

Currently I'm trying to use Vlookup for the following in excel: Let's say I have 2 sheets, 1 of them has some features (e.g. "is tall") in column B matched with some keys in column G (e.g. for "is tall" the key is "physical attributes"), column E and F contain percentages of yes and no answers respectively; as these features are assigned for a word in one cell in column A features can repeat. Moreover, column G only contains data if column E (yes answers) is greater than 50% therefore some some rows in column G are blank. In sheet 2 I have the same features but I don't have the keys written down, I'm using VLOOKUP to find the feature in sheet 1 and then write the key from sheet 1. However, some cells show up blank, my thought process is that as some features are repeated and have a blank key it is being overwritten and therefore displays the wrong output (Blank cell). My complete function is:

```
=IF($E2<0.5,"",VLOOKUP($B2,'Tx1'!$B$2:$G$392,6,FALSE))
```

The IF statement checks the percentage in the current sheet (sheet 2) if it is less than 50% it leaves it blank (this output has the correct behavior) if it is bigger than 50% it checks for the feature ($B2) in sheet 1 ("Tx1") and grabs the key from column 6 (G in the table). Is there any way to solve the problem of the data being overwritten?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
This is sheet 1 as you can see the key for the feature "large in size" is "Physical Attribute/Characteristics"

[image: Sheet 1]

This is sheet 2 as you can see for the feature "large in size" for the same word (col A) appears shows as 0. I also wrote some words un blue just to explain why those boxes were empty.

[image: Sheet 2]

Sheet 1 contains words with the same feature for another word in col A but because the feature does not match the word, the yes answer is below 50% and the key is empty.

[image: Empty Box Sheet 1]

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you mean by the data being overwritten? Are you dragging/placing the formula over old data?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` does not overwrite data. Could you please [edit your question] and post sample data showing what the problem is? It would make things a lot easier to follow

Comment: edits have been added. @BruceWayne Im dragging the formula over empty boxes in col G.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem your `VLOOKUP` is displaying correct data, but it works differently than you assume. It always returns first match that it finds therefore if there is "large in size" in table for "parsley" which has lower row number than "large in size" that is in table for "wolf" then it will return the value from column G for the line in "parsley" box. In order to return the one from "wolf" table you need to make sure it knows to look for "wolf" in column A.

If you really want to use `VLOOKUP` you would need to create an additional column - something like a combo of columns A and B (example in format `A1&" - "&B1` would be `wolf - large in size`) and you can use `VLOOKUP` on that column to get the correct value.

Alternatively you can keep your structure and you will need to use a different function that can use two parameters for search. Something like

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!G:G;MATCH(1;(Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A1)*(Sheet1!B:B=Sheet2!B1);0))
```

entered as array formula (Ctrl+shift+Enter). This assumes that you copy down the name in column A to be next to every value in column B.